# The xyz background does not rendering

Tags: qgis-3, gdal2tiles, xyz-tiles

I am trying to use the orthophotos as my background in project. I have used gdal2tiles to prepare the tiles for xyz. Then in the next step, I have uploaded the folder in our server. Then I make a new connection to xyz tiles with the following example link--->   [https://xxxxx.xxxx.solutions/planning_storage/xxxxx/{z}/{x}/{y}.png](https://xxxxx.xxxx.solutions/planning_storage/xxxxx/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png)

The xyz is made but I can not read it in my QGIS.
I am using QGIS 3.16 in Windows 10.

Comment: Can you give us the gdal2tiles command you used? You can anonymize your path/directory if confidential

Answer (score 2):

By default, gdal2tiles generate xyz tiles starting from south as quoted in the doc

> In the default mode (TMS), tiles at y=0 are the southern-most tiles, whereas in XYZ mode (used by OGC WMTS too), tiles at y=0 are the northern-most tiles.

You need to use `gdal2tiles.py` with `--xyz` option available with GDAL 3.1 and later. To avoid downloading/installing new GDAL version due to this, you can also get recent version of gdal2tiles at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OSGeo/gdal/master/gdal/swig/python/scripts/gdal2tiles.py

Then use

```
gdal2tiles.py --xyz --zoom=2-10 input.tif output_folder
```

or if you retrieved latest gdal2tiles.py file version

```
python gdal2tiles.py --xyz --zoom=2-10 input.tif output_folder
```

I have a full demo at https://gist.github.com/ThomasG77/e8b9281d07334f3b77eb4b45c42073d8 using French SCAN1000 tiles

Comment: thank you so much for the feedback. I try it out! My try with gdal2tiles were: `gdal2tiles --zoom=10-14 .....vrt folder` when I am writing gdal2tiles.py, python canot be called!

Comment: Thank you so much! I am trying it out

Comment: Not sure why you mentioned `gdal2tiles` where it should `gdal2tiles.py`. Also, if you have issues with Python just calling `gdal2tiles.py`, you can do `python exact/path/to/gdal2tiles.py` (a way to bypass configuration due to PATH)